# Iphone badge number after delete the application

Tags: iphone, badge

In my application I will show the badge number in springboard icon. But after the user deletes the application and installs it again, the badge number automatically shows up on the springboard icon.

My question is how to set the badge number to 0 when user deletes my application.
Which method it will trigger when user deletes the application?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Water, I think you might have got the solution for this.Since I make it, it;s somewhat Tricky!!!Let me know if you want any help from me.

Comment: @AjaySharma I need your help. I want to remove the badge when user deleted the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should update the badge number the next time the user runs your application.

The only other way to update the badge number is with a push notification, which isn't what you want here.